# Network monitor - delay

Tags: networking, kali-linux, monitoring

I am currently running Kali Linux on Raspberry Pi 2 and using it as network monitor. I have developed my own C application with libpcap and I am getting average delay on LAN about 300 microseconds, but the delays range from 260 to 400. Is there some way to minimize the delay range without making kernel module?

Comment: the system is supposed to buffer captures; be sure to apply filters too. Are you sure you have that many traffic to worry about? Depending on network load, I would be more worried about I/O to screen and disk than the actual network capture.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is because of the schedule try to run your app with a different scheduling policy ("real-time" policy supported for special time-critical applications):

   ```
   sudo chrt prio ./your-app
   ```

On my system prio is a number between 1 and 99. And this is recomendation: 2 - 49   Range used for typical application priorities. This is an example:

```
    sudo chrt 49 ./your-app
```

2. If it is not enough than you can try to isolate one core from being used by the schedule. I read about it in an article about low-latency programming but have not done it myself. Anyway, this is info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583146/whole-one-core-dedicated-to-single-process, http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re46.html